# If dentro de um <form> em php

Tags: php

Bom dia pessoal, preciso fazer um *IF* para um condicional no código abaixo, mas estou encontrando algumas dificuldades, o *IF* não esta executando.

preciso que o perfil de *"Coordenadores AINEC"* seja redirecionado para uma outra pagina (coordenadores.php) e não a que está no `<form class="contact-form" method="POST" action="envia.php">`.

```
                <form class="contact-form" method="POST" action="envia.php">
                    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Nome" name="nome" required="">
                    <input type="email" class="input" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" required="">
                    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Telefone" name="telefone" required="">
                    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Documento de Identificação (CPF, Passaporte)" name="documento" required="">
                    <div>
                        <label>País de origem: </label>
                    <select name="nacionalidade" id="paises">
                            <option value="Brasil" selected="selected">Brasil</option>
                            <option value="Afeganistão">Afeganistão</option>
                            <option value="África do Sul">África do Sul</option>
                            <option value="Albânia">Albânia</option>
                            <option value="Alemanha">Alemanha</option>
                            <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                            <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                            <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
                            <option value="Antilhas Holandesas">Antilhas Holandesas</option>
                            <option value="Antárctida">Antárctida</option>
                            <option value="Antígua e Barbuda">Antígua e Barbuda</option>
                            <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                            <option value="Argélia">Argélia</option>
                            <option value="Armênia">Armênia</option>
                            <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
```

.............

```
                    <br>
                    <div>

                        <label>Perfil:  </label>
                    <select name="perfil" required="" >

                          <option value="Alunos da rede Adventista de São Paulo">Alunos da rede Adventista de São Paulo(UNASP)</option> <!-- 120 reais -->
                          <option value="Alunos e Professores">Alunos e Professores - Instituições Adventistas</option> <!-- 120 reais -->
                          <option value="Profissionais da Saude">Profissionais da Saude</option> <!-- 200 reais -->
                          <option value="Coordenadores AINEC" selected="selected">Coordenadores AINEC-LA</option> <!-- 500 reais -->


                    </select>
                   </div>

                   <br>


                     <div class="aviso" >
                        <label><strong><font color="#FF0000">IMPORTANTE !!!</font></strong></label><br>
                        <li><label> As inscrições só serão concluídas após o Pagamento.</label><br></li>
                        <li><label> Não esqueça de verificar se o seu perfil está correto.</label></li>



                    </div>

                   <br>

                    <button class="main-btn">Finalizar Inscrição</button> 
                </form>
```

Comment: Onde está o `if`?

Comment: Fica em <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
     
     <form class="contact-form" method="POST" action="envia.php">

      <?php if ($perfil == "Coordenadores AINEC"): ?>

       <form class="contact-form" method="POST" action="coordenadores.php">
       
      <?php endif ?>
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Nome" name="nome" required="">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o `Select` e o `Form` não possuem `id` eu atribui, perfil e Form1, respectivamente.

Como o botão de envio não é um `submit`, pelo q entendi é só fazer um `if`mudando a `action` do `form`baseado no perfil escolhido:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#perfil").on('change', function(){
    if ($("#perfil").val() == "Coordenadores AINEC") {
        $('#form1').attr('action','coordenadores.php');
        $('#form1').submit();
    }else{
        $('#form1').attr('action','envia.php');
        $('#form1').submit();
    }
})
 </script>
```

Edit - 1: esqueci de avisar que estou usando jquery.

Comment: Acho que ficou faltando você incluir o evento 'onChange' do select para disparar o código que você escreveu.

Comment: Num é que faltem um evento mesmo!
Valeu @LeandroCastro, vou corrigir.

Comment: poderia ter usado também $("#perfil").change(function.... direto ao inves do .on(), de toda forma tá certo.

Comment: deu certo!! obrigado pela ajuda pessoal.